# Is it true that $X\simeq S^2\vee S^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be the quotient space of $S^2$ under the identifications $x\sim -x$ for every $x$ in the equator $S^1$. Is it true that $X\simeq S^2\vee S^2$, that is, $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^2\vee S^2$?

Comment: If you take away the attaching point in the wedge sum you disconnect the space. Whatever point you take away in the quotient space the result will still be connected, so, no, they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Though you "reduce" one diameter, it does *not* become a point but rather a line segment, and thus this cannot be hom. to $\;S^2\vee S^2\;$

Comment: Usually we reserve $\cong$ for homeomorphic and $\simeq$ for homotopy equivalent. Which did you mean here? - these spaces are neither homeomorphic nor homotopy equivalent, but the proof of these two facts differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider the cellular homology with $\Bbbk=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$-coefficients. Both spaces are CW complexes, the quotient space $X=S^2/\sim$ has a CW complex structure with one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell and two $2$-cells attached to the one skeleton (a circle) by degree $2$ maps, while the wedge sum $Y=S^2\vee S^2$ has a CW structure with one $0$ cell and two $2$ cells. Their cellular homology (with $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$-coefficients) is the homology of the complex
$$0\to \Bbbk\oplus\Bbbk\xrightarrow{0}\Bbbk\xrightarrow{0}\Bbbk\to 0$$
for $X$, and
$$0\to \Bbbk\oplus\Bbbk\to0\to\Bbbk\to 0$$
fro $Y$. The differentials are all $0$ (obvious for the second one, and follows from the degree $2$ remark above for the first one), so that the complexes are already the homology. Since they are different, the two spaces cannot be homeomorphic or even homotopy equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not true. On $S^2 \vee S^2$ there is a unique point which has no neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. On $X$, there are infinitely many such points.